# Que signifie par le fait que dans cette phrase?

Tags: grammaire, sens, expressions, verbes

Quelles traces dans les événements par le fait que la nécessité historique a été accomplie à telle époque, de telle manière?

il me semble que cette phrase n'a pas de verbe.

Comment: « a été » est le verbe être au passé composé.

Comment: Il serait utile d'ajouter un peu de contexte à cette question. D'où provient cette phrase ? Qu'est-ce qui la précède ?

Comment: [« Et il sera toujours juste de demander quelles traces a laissées l'individu ; quelles tracces... »](https://books.google.com/books?newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&id=i8LVAAAAMAAJ&dq=traces+dans+les+%C3%A9v%C3%A9nements+par+le+fait+que+la+n%C3%A9cessit%C3%A9+historique+a+%C3%A9t%C3%A9+accomplie+%C3%A0+telle+%C3%A9poque%2C+de+telle+mani%C3%A8re%3F&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=quelles+traces)

Comment: Reconstruire la phrase : La nécessité historique *a été* accomplie à telle époque, de telle manière [ Question comment la connaît-on ? ] ***Par le fait que*** les événements de ce cette époque laissent des traces | ***En raison des/À cause des*** événements de ce cette époque ***qui*** laissent des traces

Comment: C'est une phrase tronquée. Il faut poster la phrase entière.

Answer (score 1):

La phrase complète remise dans son contexte est (merci @Diversité):

> Et il sera toujours juste de demander quelles traces a laissées l'individu ; **quelles traces dans les événements par le fait que la nécessité historique a été accomplie à telle époque, de telle manière ?** quelles traces dans la création culturelle ? En quelle mesure le protestantisme porte-t-il la marque de Luther, l'islamisme celle de Mahomet ?
> Raymon Aron, *Introduction à la philosophie de l'histoire*, 1948.

La phrase a donc un verbe, le verbe *être* (*Et il **sera** toujours juste[...]*)

***Par le fait*** précise que cette trace est liée, assujettie à l'époque où a vécu l'individu étudié ainsi qu'à la manière avec laquelle il a accompli ce dont il est question.

Comment: pour moi le verbe c est demander, mais il est sous-entendu car il s agit d une enumeratiion, les propositions qui suivent la premiere phrase sont des complements d objet et ont poir role de préciser celui de la premiere phrase.

Comment: @EmmanuelBRUNO Oui *demander* est sous-entendu (*demander quelles traces [...]* etc.), mais  comme tu l'écris, il ne s'agit pas de phrases mais d'une suite de propositions.

Answer (score 0):

« Par le fait que » signifie que la raison de ce qui est décrit par ce qui précède la locution est due à l'action décrite dans ce qui suit la locution.

Il manque un  verbe, pas de doute ; quant à trouver lequel est le plus probable choix   ce n'est pas possible : les idées sont trop générales.

- Quelles traces dans les événements **< verbe >** par le fait que la nécessité historique a été accomplie à telle époque, de telle manière?